# How to run for number of seconds python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, time, pygame

I my pygame game I have powerups spawning. When the player collects them it gets a special power up. How can I make the powerups only run for a certain number of seconds? Since I wouldn't want them to run forever

This is where the problem is

```
for p in p_power:
    if man.hitbox[0] < p.hitbox[0] + p.hitbox[2] < man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] or man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > p.hitbox[0] > man.hitbox[0]:
        if man.hitbox[1] <= p.hitbox[1] + p.hitbox[3]:
            if p.index == 0:  # health power up, ads one to the health
                if man.health < 10:
                    man.health += 1
                p_power.pop(p_power.index(p))

            elif p.index == 1:
                while p_end > 0: # Problem! tries to run for 10 seconds. Makes the players gun cooldown less so that it can shoot faster for 10 secs
                    delay.cooldown = 75
```

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python timer", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: This can be done by using [pygame.time.set_timer][https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer]. You can start the powerup, and create a delayed event which will stop the powerup when the time is elapsed. Sadly, cannot help you more, since the snippet code you provided is unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not that familiar with `pygame` and this snippet does not provide an incredible amount of context.

Maybe something like this?

```
import datetime

for p in p_power:
    if man.hitbox[0] < p.hitbox[0] + p.hitbox[2] < man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] or man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > p.hitbox[0] > man.hitbox[0]:
        if man.hitbox[1] <= p.hitbox[1] + p.hitbox[3]:
            if p.index == 0:  # health power up, ads one to the health
                if man.health < 10:
                    man.health += 1
                p_power.pop(p_power.index(p))

            elif p.index == 1:
                p_start = datetime.datetime.now()
                while (datetime.datetime.now() - p_start).seconds => 10: 
                    # Do the powerup
                    # Don't know if this belongs in a while loop though, maybe should be an if statement
                    # Is this called in the main game loop synchronously?
                    pass
```

As I commented in the code, I'm not sure if that really belongs in a `while` loop. Is this snippet called at some point synchronously in the main game loop? If so, it should probably be checked similarly with an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time`:

```
import time
```

Define a function as `start_time = time.time()` which you can use anywhere in your function, and then with `(start_time - time.time())` you can check how much has passed since you started your variable `start_time` and use it with `if` or `while` to set the powerups.

```
for p in p_power:
    if man.hitbox[0] < p.hitbox[0] + p.hitbox[2] < man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] or man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > p.hitbox[0] > man.hitbox[0]:
        if man.hitbox[1] <= p.hitbox[1] + p.hitbox[3]:
            if p.index == 0:  # health power up, ads one to the health
                if man.health < 10:
                    man.health += 1
                p_power.pop(p_power.index(p))

            elif p.index == 1:
                start_time = time.time()
                while p_end > 0: # Problem! tries to run for 10 seconds. Makes the players gun cooldown less so that it can shoot faster for 10 secs
                    while (time.time()-start_time) <= 10:
                        delay.cooldown = 75
```